# Deleting a xml node in c using libxml library function

Tags: c, libxml2

I want to delete a xmlNode from a XmlNodeptr. For Example from the following figure I want to delete the node 'XX' (along with its children here 'm'). How can I do that using c language libxml library??? Is there any direct library function for that?

```
<PP>
    <ABCD>
        <XX>
            <m>1</m>
        </XX>
    </ABCD>
</PP>
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply use [`xmlUnlinkNode`](http://xmlsoft.org/html/libxml-tree.html#xmlUnlinkNode), possibly followed by `xmlFreeNode`. From the documentation:

```
void xmlUnlinkNode (xmlNodePtr cur)
```

> Unlink a node from it's current context, the node is not freed. If one need to free the node, use `xmlFreeNode()` routine after the unlink to discard it. Note that namespace nodes can't be unlinked as they do not have pointer to their parent.